# Number of connected components of complement of plane curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, plane-curves

Let $$P(x,y)=\sum_{k=0}^m\sum_{l=0}^n a_{k,l}x^k y^l$$ be a polynomial over $\mathbb R$ in $x$ and $y$ of degree $m+n$. The zero locus
$$\mathcal C=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2\,|\, P(x,y)=0\}$$
is a plane algebraic curve. How many connected components does $\mathbb R^2\backslash \mathcal C$ have?

Comment: That depends on your explicit curve. The circle yields 2 components, but there are other curves with some sort of loop, which yield at least 3 components...

Comment: I imagine that you expect bounds for the answer as otherwise, the answer is depending on the values of the coefficients ?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I am wondering if there is a general statement. Of course the answer depends crucially on $m$, $n$ and $a_{k,l}\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: I doubt that such an answer exists knowing the complexity to answer the much simpler question *what is the number of real roots of a real polynomial of degree $n$?*

Comment: That is a bit disappointing. I was expecting the question to turn out to be stupid, as I'm not familiar at all with algebraic geometry. Do you know if the question can be answered in principle if $m$ and $n$ are small? For instance, if the curve is real elliptic, then the answer would be 3 or 2, depending on the discriminant

Comment: @ElRafu : in general, the best you can have is a bound by Harnack. I'm not sure you'll get anything concrete to compute these components even for small $m,n$.

Comment: For nonsingular $C$ (e.g. for generic values of coefficients), the number of complementary components is $c+1$, where $c$ is the number of components of the curve $C$ itself.

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet I was not aware of that bound, thanks! I'm searching for more precise statements unfortunately.

Comment: @MoisheKohan That was my intuition, thanks.

Comment: Harnak bound says that a nonsingular real algebraic curve of genus $g$ has at  most $g+1$ real components. The genus is related to degree (for irreducible curves) by the [genus-degree formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus%E2%80%93degree_formula), $g=(d-1)(d-2)/2$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan : I should have said that Harnack bounds only works for projective curves. For affine curves the bound has to be modified (it should be something like $g+d$ if I'm not mistaken).

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet: True, I was careless.

Comment: @MoisheKohan : not at all, your comment relating number of components of the complement and the number of component of the curves was quite useful, since I didn't explain how to use Harnack bound to answer to the question !